# How to combine the values from multiple rows in a column (separated by commas) where there are duplicates in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a large dataset where I want to combine the values of multiple rows in one column where there are duplicates in another column. See my Example below:

## CURRENT DATA

| Product Type | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | abc@gmail.com |
| Product 2 | abc@gmail.com |
| Product 3 | abc@gmail.com |
| Product 4 | abc@gmail.com |
| Product 1 | xyz@gmail.com |
| Product 2 | xyz@gmail.com |

## REQUIRED DATA

| Product Type | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, Product 4 | abc@gmail.com |
| Product 1, Product 2 | xyz@gmail.com |

The values in the column "Product Type" are combined and separated by commas wherever the Emails are duplicates in the "Email" column.

Comment: newer versions of excel (2021+) would use just 3 formulas to perform this task. Unfortunately you tag with excel 2010. I don't think power query existed back, leaving you only with VBA.

Comment: @gns100 if using Excel 2021+ is an easier option I will hunt down an install. If you can share the formulas that would still be very helpful. Removing the excel 2010 tag so not to limit myself. Thanks.

Comment: for newer excel column email would be `Unique()`, then for column product type it would be something like: `Arraytotext(filter())`. good luck.

Comment: I believe these formulas are available on the free web version of excel. At least that's what I see when I checked, but don't know if my free account is somehow linked to my desktop version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power query is available as a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010+.

All you need to do is Group by email and change the m-code to concatenate the relevant rows.

I "Named" the table created "currentData" and you see that referenced in the code.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="currentData"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product Type", type text}, {"Email", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Email"}, {
        {"Products", each Text.Combine([Product Type], ", "), Text.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Products", "Email"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]